# How to combine list of abbreviations and list of symbols in the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I've used `glossaries` to keep one list of abbreviations and one list of symbols. When I print them, they're printed as two separate lists with titles and pagebreaks. How can I print them together in one list, with abbreviations first and symbols last?

I considered simply changing all symbols to define them as:

```
\newacronym[sort=zzzid]{symbol:id}{\ensuremath{1}}{The identity matrix}
\glsadd{symbol:id}
```

This would put them in the same list as abbreviations. However, this precludes me from adding a little "Symbols" header, and I'm worried I'd get problems down the line if I abused the system this way.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation} % list for symbols
\makenoidxglossaries

% Abbreviations
\newacronym[sort=ECG]{ecg}{\textsc{ecg}}{electrocardiogram}

% Symbols
\newglossaryentry{not:id}{type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{1}},
    description={Identity matrix},
    sort=1
}
\glsadd{not:id}

\begin{document}

A sentence using the abbreviation \gls{ecg}.

\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints abbreviations on separate page -- not wanted

\printnoidxglossary[type=notation]  % prints symbols on separate page -- not wanted

\end{document}
```

Comment: With standard `article` document class, the two groups are not on separate pages but listed together. I think the effect is caused by `memoir` doc. class. It is where I would start looking for answers. Here's a link to [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: @Celdor Thank you, I didn't realise.